# Selective text for mtext() based on the input argument in R?

Tags: r, function, plot, histogram

I have a vectorized R function that produces some histograms (below). I want to add an `mtext()`to one of the histograms (please locate this below).

## Question

But I want the text in the `mtext()` to change according to whether argument `n` is a vector of length > 1 OR argument `es` is a vector of length > 1.

In my code, I'm using the following piece without success:

`txt = if(length(n) > 1) "Group Sample Size = " else if(length(es) > 1) "Effect Size = " else "Group Sample Size = "`

`mtext(paste0(txt, input), 3)` [Please locate these below]

**Here is my complete R code:**

```
 p.es = function(n, es, n.sim){

input = if(length(n) > 1) n else if(length(es) > 1) es else n

t.sim = Vectorize(function(n, es){

d = numeric(n.sim)
p = numeric(n.sim)

for(i in 1:n.sim){
   N = sqrt((n^2)/(2*n))
   x = rnorm(n, es, 1)
   y = rnorm(n, 0, 1)
   a = t.test(x, y, var.equal = TRUE)
d[i] = a[[1]]/N
p[i] = a[[3]] }

txt = if(length(n) > 1) "Group Sample Size = " else if(length(es) > 1) "Effect Size = " else "Group Sample Size = "
hist(p) ; mtext(paste0(txt, input), 3) ## Here I need help!!!!

hist(d) 
}, c("n", "es"))

par(mfcol = c(2, length(input)), xpd = NA)
invisible(t.sim(n, es)) }
# Example of use:
p.es(n = 20, es = c(.1, .2), n.sim = 20) # Here I expect the mtext to show "Effect Size = "
                                         # but it doesn't why?
```

Comment: When `input` is a vector with 2 or more elements, your `mtext` call is printing multiple strings at the same position. For example `Effect size = 0.1` and `Effect size = 0.2` are overlaid.

Comment: @DamianoFantini, yes but what do you suggest to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with `mtext` of your `if...else` statements. It looks the problem happens because of `Vectorize`. Let's start with your inner function, here called `myfun`. It seems to work nicely.

```
myfun <- function(n, es, nsim, input){

  d = numeric(n.sim)
  p = numeric(n.sim)

  for(i in 1:n.sim){
    N = sqrt((n^2)/(2*n))
    x = rnorm(n, es, 1)
    y = rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    a = t.test(x, y, var.equal = TRUE)
    d[i] = a[[1]]/N
    p[i] = a[[3]] }

  txt <- if (length(n) > 1) {"Group Sample Size = "} else if (length(es) > 1) {"Effect Size = "} else {"Group Sample Size = "}
  hist(p) ; mtext(paste0(txt, input, collapse = " "), 3) ## Here I need help!!!!

  hist(d) 
}

# Test Run
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
myfun(n = 10, 
      es = c(0.1, 0.2), 
      nsim = 10, 
      input = c(0.1, 0.2))
```

[image]

Now, if you implement `Vectorize`, the problem appears.

```
t.sim <- Vectorize(myfun, c('n', 'es', 'nsim', 'input'))
n <- 10
n.sim <- 10
es <- c(0.1, 0.2)
input <- c(0.1, 0.2)
t.sim(n, es, n.sim, input)
```

[image]

One way to fix this is to move the `txt` assignment outside the `Vectorize` call (can you assign the value of `txt` when you define `input`?).

```
p.es = function(n, es, n.sim){

  input = if(length(n) > 1) n else if(length(es) > 1) es else n
  txt = if(length(n) > 1) "Group Sample Size = " else if(length(es) > 1) "Effect Size = " else "Group Sample Size = "

  t.sim = Vectorize(function(n, es){
    d = numeric(n.sim)
    p = numeric(n.sim)

    for(i in 1:n.sim){
      N = sqrt((n^2)/(2*n))
      x = rnorm(n, es, 1)
      y = rnorm(n, 0, 1)
      a = t.test(x, y, var.equal = TRUE)
      d[i] = a[[1]]/N
      p[i] = a[[3]] }

    hist(p) ; mtext(paste0(txt, paste(input, collapse = "-")), 3) ## Here I need help!!!!

    hist(d) 
  }, c("n", "es"))

  par(mfcol = c(2, length(input)), xpd = NA)
  invisible(t.sim(n, es)) }
# Example of use:
p.es(n = 20, es = c(.1, .2), n.sim = 20) # Is this what you want?
```

[image]

Comment: Damiano, thank you so much! But yes, I need `Vectorize`, and note that even though I have vectorized both `n` and `es`, I will not need to simultaneously use `n` and `es` of lenghth > 1. Rather, I will use either `n` with length > 1 OR `es` with length > 1. So, all I want the function to know is that it matches up (synchs) the text within the `mtext()` with the output of object `input`, that's all!

Comment: Then what I would do is to assign `txt` outside the `Vectorize` f(x). Otherwise, I don't really know. I updated the answer to show this, btw

Comment: Unfortunately, there is problem with your updated answer, the last part, look at the generated mtext  closely to catch this.

Comment: What? If you refer to the 0.1-0.2 thing, I just collapsed the values of input together. If you want just one number to be displayed, you have to decide which one to put there...

Comment: Ah! sorry, got it, thank you! oh no, there are further problems, but forget about it! It is taking our time.